# AbstractController::ActionNotFound with form_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

When I use `form_tag` as below then I get this error:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /quizzes/[whichever_quiz_id]
>
> The action 'whichever_quiz_id' could not be found for QuizzesController

My code is as below:

**erb file**

```
<%= form_tag action: :add_questions  do %>
  <%= collection_select(:quiz, :id, Quiz.where.not(id: params[:id]), :name, :id, prompt: 'Select Quiz') %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:input_quiz_questions, 'Question ids') %>
  <%= submit_tag "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

So here I have a method in my `QuizController` called `add_questions` which takes a selected question from another Quiz and adds it to the present Quiz.

```
def add_questions
  id = params[:id]
  required_quiz_id = params[:quiz][:id].to_i #taken from collection_select
  required_questions_ids = params[:input_quiz_questions].split().map { |s| s.to_i } #taken from text_field_tag
  # remaining logic here
```

**routes**

```
resources :quizzes, as: 'tests' do
  member do
    get :add_questions
  end
end
```

So why am I getting the above error here and how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write after form_tag the url, not the name of the action in the option hash

```
<%= form_tag quizzes_add_questions_path, method: :get  do %>
```